# vue-cli: Error when trying to load an image from assets folder

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I'm using vue-cli 3 and I I have this style:

```
.login-page {
  ...
  background: url("~@/assets/login-bg.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  ...
}
```

When i run `yarn serve` I get this error:

> ./src/assets/login-bg.jpg Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/url-loader/index.js): TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]:
>   The "id" argument must be of type string. Received type object
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:630:11)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
>       at Object.module.exports (C:\aquaprojects\src\bitbucket.org\scalock\server\tmui\node_modules\url-loader\index.js:35:24)

I have no problem loading SVG's, what am I missing?

Comment: should it not be either ~ or @ in your `background: url("...`

Comment: In JS it's `@`, in style it's `~@`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but I deleted my node_modules and re-installed and it works

Comment: sometimes you need to restart your windows, so thinks work again ;-)